# How do i convert a sting into a variable?

Tags: javascript

```
var activePlayer = 0;

var currentScore0 = 0;

var currentScore1 = 0 ;

var player ="currentScore"+activePlayer;
```

This gives me a string "currentScore0" how do I get the value from the variable currentScore0

Comment: Don't do that; have an array `currentScore = [0, 0]` and then you can just `currentScore[activePlayer]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the "eval" function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window["currentScore"+activePlayer]` to access that variable's value but you should find a better way of storing this info so it will be easier to access it.

Here is an example of storing the info:

```
var players = [{
                id: 1,
                score: 0,
                active: true
              }, {
                id: 2,
                score: 0,
                active: false
              }, getPlayer: function(id){
                   return this.find(player => player.id == id);
              }];
```

Then you can do:

```
  var playerOneScore = players.getPlayer(1).score;
```